# Servlet address is incorrect

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to create a servlet and I am using Tomcat 7 .
I added a folder for my application in the webapps folder and it looks like this :

```
--[webapps]
    --[agtel]
        --[web-inf]
           --[classes]
              --add.class
           --web.xml
        --index.html
```

web.xml contains :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>add</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and index.html contains :

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="/add">
```

When I press the submit button it tries to access this :

```
http://localhost:8080/add
```

which results in a 404 error. but if I change it to

```
http://localhost:8080/agtel/add
```

then of course it executes the applet

So I tried changing the URL in the html file to

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="agtel/add">
```

But then it tries to access :

```
http://localhost:8080/agtel/agtel/add
```

Why does it add the name twice now ? This is very confusing and is driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you try `ACTION="add"`, or `ACTION="/agtel/add"`?

Comment: `ACTION="add"` and as the servlet context root is `/agtel` the url is `/agtel/add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using URL in HTML, without leading / they are relative to the current URL. With leading / they are absolute :

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="/agtel/add">
```

or

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="add">
```

will do what you want.

I suggest you to add the context inside the action path dinamically example (in JSP) :

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add">
```

With this you will never have to change the path, for example if you move your file or copy your code. Of course you need a index.jsp for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the so called "Context" path. In case you are running multiple applications on the same Tomcat (or whatever application server) it differentiates the access to them.
When you change your path from "/add" to "add" (no leading slash) it should work fine!

Comment: That was it! I saw with the slash in an example (which worked) and thought that's how it was supposed to be. Thank you very much!